# How to initalize and populate TWideStringDynArray in Pascal?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am calling a function for SOAP service and one of the required parameters is TWideStringDynArray. How do I initialize and populate this type of array? Or is there another way to convert a normal array to this type?

This is how it's defined in SOAP class

```
...

ArrayOfString = TWideStringDynArray;

...

PrsDataGet = class(TRemotable)
private
FsRetVal: WideString;
FsInParam: ArrayOfString;
published
property sRetVal: WideString read FsRetVal write FsRetVal;
property sInParam: ArrayOfString read FsInParam write FsInParam;
end;
```

If i set `FsInParam` as a array of WideString it says incompatible types

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
QuotePrice : Real;
rezultat:WideString;

mnozica:array [0..4] of integer;

parametri: array of WideString;
obstaja:boolean;

PrsGet:PrsDataGet;

PrsFind:PrsDataGet;

begin

PrsGet.sRetVal :=rezultat;

SetLength(parametri, 4);

parametri[0]:= '1234';
parametri[1]:= 'wsprsinfotest';
parametri[2]:= 'efwefawf';
parametri[3]:= 'PRS_MN_P';


PrsGet.sInParam :=parametri;
```

If i change type of `parametri` to `ArrayOfString` it doesn't complain of incompatible types anymore but then it throws an Access Violation at `SetLength(parametri, 4);`

**EDIT**
To reproduce the problem:

I import WSDL definition into delphi from https://wwwt.ajpes.si/wsPrsInfo/PrsInfo.asmx?WSDL

Code for the service call:

```
    unit UnKlicServisa;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Rio, SoapHTTPClient,Types,
  UnWsPrsInfo_1, UnWsPrsInfo_2;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    HTTPRIO1: THTTPRIO;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;

    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rezultat:WideString;
  parametri:  ArrayOfString;
  obstaja:boolean;

  PrsGet:PrsDataGet;

begin

PrsGet.sRetVal :=rezultat;

parametri[0]:= '1234';
parametri[1]:= 'wsprsinfotest';
parametri[2]:= '3423445';
parametri[3]:= 'PRS_MN_P';


PrsGet.sInParam :=parametri;


  if Trim(Edit1.Text) <> '' then
  begin
        (HTTPRIO1 as PrsInfoSoap).PrsDataGet(PrsGet);

  end
  else
  begin
     MessageDlg('Enter a Valid ISBN code',mtInformation,[mbOk],0);
     Edit1.SetFocus;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You should be able to pass any type of wide string array there.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Please check my post edit.

Comment: Access violation doesn't seem plausible. Can you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do we need SOAP to reproduce? Can this be made smaller?

Comment: I'm new to delphi so i don't know how to simplify this

Comment: Don’t know why it works  at all, because looking at your code, you’re not constructing the object `PrsGet`. So ther e should always be an AV exception....

Comment: @R.Hoek i fixed it, i still have a problem initializing TWideStringDynArray tho

Answer (score 0):

Note FPC 3.2.0+ also allows array constructors

```
{$mode Delphi}
uses types;

var arr : TWideStringDynArray;

begin
  arr:=TWideStringDynArray.Create('1234','wsprsinfotest','efwefawf','PRS_MN_P');
end.
```

Comment: This throws an error when you create `arr`: "Object or class type required."

Comment: It compiles with stock 3.2.0+. But as said, this is FPC 3.2.0+ functionality, so make sure your install is not outdated. In Delphi it is afaik also a feature of a later version. Please specify compiler and version in your question next time

Comment: How can i check which version of Pascal am i using. I use Delphi 6 to compile the code.

Comment: Delphi 6 is enough info, but simply always mention such details when asking a question. It makes it easier for the answerers. And no, D6 is ancient, and probably won't support that syntax.